# Rails + ActiveRecord + Postgres: How to match case insensitive substring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have to look for all emails from the `User` model that have the substring "cpg". So it would match "cpg@yahoo.com", "cpg3333@yahoo.com", etc

I'm pretty sure how to do case insensitive (using `User.where("lower(email)...")` but I don't know how to find a substring.

I'm using Rails 3 + Postgres 9.x

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing in Rails to do it, you can just use PostgreSQL's `ilike` (case insensitive like function).

Like so: `User.where("email ilike '%cpg%'")`

Comment: Be aware that this can cause performance problems: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-types.html

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to have to always remember to call `lower(email)` (and `input.downcase` on your input in Ruby) whenever you search on your email field, you can make the `email` column itself case insensitive by using the `citext` data type.

That's what I just did.  I created a migration like this:

```
class ChangeUsersEmailToCitext < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    # Rails 4:
    #enable_extension("citext")
    # Rails 3:
    execute 'create extension citext'

    change_table :users do |t|
      t.change :email, :citext
    end
  end
end
```

And now I no longer have to do any extra effort to make the queries case insensitive!  It's all handled automatically for me behind the scenes now.

This uses PostgreSQL's [citext](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/citext.html) extension.

http://www.sfcgeorge.co.uk/posts/2013/11/12/case-insensitive-usernames-with-postgres has a nice article about this.

Comment: Isn't PostgreSQL great? :) The only thing I've wished for since doing this is that it had the ability to preserve the case as the user entered it, for display purposes (FirstLast@Domain.com, for example), but still allow searching to be case-insensitive. I guess I'd need 2 columns to accomplish that...

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you're not calling `downcase` before you enter it?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I must have some kind of before filter or something that's doing that automatically, because when I test it on the dbconsole, I see that you are right... `update users set email = 'FirstLast@Example.com' where id = 1; select email from users where id = 1;` Thanks, I learned something new!

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you can do this in Rails agnostically: http://robb.weblaws.org/2013/12/05/yes-rails-supports-case-insensitive-database-queries/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - works without code specifically tied to a particular database engine.

Comment: First example doesn't use the squeel gem!

Comment: There's a reason Arel isn't well documented - it's an internal Rails API that is not recommended to be used by third-party apps.

Comment: Link is dead now, sadly

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

`User.where('LOWER(email) = LOWER(?)', search_email)`

Option 2: 
Use Postgres'  [citex](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/citext.html) extension which will do it for you (as answered above).